# Room and Kotlin - getting "Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am getting this error:

```
error: Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter. Cannot find method parameters for :network.
error: Unused parameter: arg0
```

when trying Room and Kotlin like this:

```
@Dao
interface TokenDefinitionDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM token_descriptors WHERE network LIKE :network")
    fun getAllForNetwork(network: String?): List<TokenDescriptor>

    @Delete
    fun delete(token: TokenDescriptor)
}
```

But I am passing and using this parameter. Anyone sees what the problem is or can point me to working examples of using Room with Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change "network" param to "arg0"

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM token_descriptors WHERE network LIKE :arg0")
```

In newer versions of kotlin and room this issue was fixed!

Comment: Encountered this issue even when not using Kotlin anywhere project. This solved it

Comment: Facing the same issue with Java when my dao is in a module and database class in application. Room v2.2.5

Answer (score 4):

To avoid that problem you have to use kotlin-kapt plugin in your build.gradle.

```
...

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...

android {
...
}
```

btw, ensure that you're using kotlin 1.2.0+

Comment: I am getting: 
Error:Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3-eap-85.
Searched in the following locations:

Comment: @MladenRakonjac I've updated my answer. Check it please.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the 'kotlin-kapt' apply plugin. Everything worked fine until this query issue, amusingly.